# input to behave as a number field for desktop and mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input field like below in app where I have put it as a type number. User can click up and down to increase the number or can input the value in the field.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" min="1">
```

But when I go to mobile, the same field is behaving like a text field. Is there anything I can do about it?

Suggest.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=number

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: Use plugins for cross-browser support

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for validation, by using the below code the user can't even drag and drop numbers in the text box, just give the class name of the text box as "numericOnly".

```
$(function () {
    $(".numericOnly").bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '9' || e.keyCode == '16') {
            return;
        }
        var code;
        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) code = e.which;
        //if (e.which == 46)
        // return false;
        if (code == 8 || code == 46)
            return true;
        if (code < 48 || code > 57)
            return false;
    }
    );
    $(".numericOnly").bind("paste", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".numericOnly").bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val != '0') {
            val = val.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "")
            $(this).val(val);
        }
    });
});
```